# Excel VBA Code, moving multiple files to specific folders

Tags: vba, excel

I have over 100,000 files (.PDF and a few .XLS) that need moved from one Folder to another.  I have three things i'm working with: The source Folder (A), The Destination Folder (B), and the Excel document stating where the files should go.

Folder A: the 100,000+ files

Folder B: 100's of folders already pre-named

Excel File: Column B lists the documents name. Column C lists the destination of were to go in "Folder B".

I need to move all files according to their specific location based on the excel document.  I've seen some code regarding moving files; however, this is more complex.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code have you found? Probably use a third Excel sheet and just use that to reference the destination folders, then run the code to move the files.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that should do the job. However, I am worried about whether the hard disk can keep up with the speed of VBA. So, inserted a `DoEvents` into each loop. Frankly, I don't know if that is the correct cure.

```
Sub MoveFiles()
    ' 01 Oct 2017

    ' This is the address of your folder "A", must end on a path separator:
    Const SourcePath As String = "C:\My Documents\A\"
    ' This is the address of your folder "B", must end on a path separator:
    Const TargetPath As String = "C:\My Documents\B\"

    Dim Fn As String                        ' file name
    Dim Fold As String                      ' folder name in "B"
    Dim R As Long                           ' row counter

    With ActiveSheet
        ' start in row 2, presuming 1 to have captions:
        For R = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            Fn = Trim(.Cells(R, "B").Value)
            Fold = Trim(.Cells(R, "C").Value)
'            Debug.Print SourcePath & Fn & " = " & TargetPath & Fold & "\" & Fn
            Name SourcePath & Fn As TargetPath & Fold & "\" & Fn
            DoEvents
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

I tested the above code on a folder with 380 files and found no problem except that the `Name` function rejected a file name containing the character "ä" (Chr(0228). This caused me to add a Messagebox to be displayed in case of failure. The new code below also creates and directories in folder "B" which might not exist. I did this to save the time of setting up all the sub folders, and you could, too.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveFiles()
    ' 02 Oct 2017

    Dim Src As String                       ' source path
    Dim Dest As String                      ' Target path
    Dim Fn As String                        ' file name
    Dim Fold As String                      ' folder name in "B"
    Dim Rl As Long                          ' last row in column B
    Dim R As Long                           ' row counter

    With ActiveSheet
        If TestPaths(Src, Dest) Then
            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    '        ' start in row 2, presuming 1 to have captions:
            For R = 2 To Rl
                Fn = Trim(.Cells(R, "B").Value)
                Fold = Dest & Trim(.Cells(R, "C").Value)
                If FolderName(Fold, True) Then
                    On Error Resume Next
        '            Debug.Print R, Src & Fn & " = " & Fold & "\" & Fn
                    Name Src & Fn As Fold & Fn
                    If Err Then
                        MsgBox "File " & Fn & vbCr & _
                               "in row " & R & " couldn't be moved." & vbCr & _
                               "Error " & Err & " - " & Err.Description
                    End If
                End If
    '            DoEvents
                If (Rl - R) Mod 50 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = Rl - R & " records remaining"
            Next R
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Function TestPaths(Src As String, _
                           Dest As String) As Boolean
    ' 02 Oct 2017
    ' both arguments are return strings

    ' This is the address of your folder "A":
    Const SourcePath As String = "C:\My Documents\A"
    ' This is the address of your folder "B":
    Const TargetPath As String = "C:\My Documents\B"

    Dim Fn As String

    Src = SourcePath
    If FolderName(Src, False) Then
        Dest = TargetPath
        TestPaths = FolderName(Dest, True)
    End If
End Function

Private Function FolderName(Ffn As String, _
                            CreateIfMissing As Boolean) As Boolean
    ' 02 Oct 2017
    ' Ffn is a return string

    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Ffn = Trim(Ffn)
    Do While Right(Ffn, 1) = "\"
        Ffn = Left(Ffn, Len(Ffn) - 1)
    Loop
    Sp = Split(Ffn, "\")
    Ffn = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
        Ffn = Ffn & Sp(i) & "\"
        On Error Resume Next
        If Len(Dir(Ffn, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            If Err Then
                MsgBox Err.Description & vbCr & _
                "Error No. " & Err, vbCritical, "Fatal error"
                Exit Function
            Else
                If CreateIfMissing Then
                    MkDir Ffn
                Else
                    MsgBox "The given path doesn't exist:" & vbCr & _
                           Ffn, vbCritical, "Set-up error"
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    FolderName = (i > 0)
End Function
```

I tested without the `DoEvents`. The method of deploying `DoEvents` as suggested by @Joshua Fenner is the one I have seen elsewhere, but I don't see why the function couldn't just do what it is said to do. Better if I don't need it, and I didn't.

However, my courage didn't go as far as to take up Joshua's suggestion to further speed up the procedure though I agree with his idea. Avoiding 100,000 accesses of the worksheet would save a lot of time. Instead, I added a progress display in the status bar (bottom left) to keep you company while you wait :-)

Please note that the paths are now set in the function `TestPaths` which you will find below the main procedure.

Comment: The Name function is quite a bit faster than a file system object!  I wonder if using 2D array for column B and C to set FN and Fold could speed this up even more?  Hit the Sheet once instead of 200,000+ times.

Comment: `DoEvents` allows you to have control of the program while it is running, so you can pause the execution at any time.  otherwise you get the "excel not responding", and everything looks hung up.

Comment: @Joshua Fenner Thanks for the input. Could you please explain further? In lay terms, what is the file system object doing? If it is changing the file's offset location then my concern is justified and making the name function faster would be the opposite of what should be done.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the explanation. I don't quite manage to reconcile what you say with MSDN where they say, "DoEvents passes control to the operating system. Control is returned after the operating system has finished processing the events in its queue". What is the "operating system" in this sentence? Applied to the above code I hoped  that control would be passed from VBA to whatever manages the disk (the operating system?) so that VBA would stop while the file system object catches up.

Comment: @jsotola As an alternative, a `Wait` or `Timer` function would suspend VBA execution, but then I might argue that the FSO is part of VBA and nothing can catch up while action is suspended. Do you have a recommendation you can explain?

Comment: @Variatus  The FSO has  a `.movefile` method.  So after you create a FSO of the file you can use it.  But this way seems faster and there is no file ghosting.  Instead of just `do events` maybe `Do While` file is not in new location`  `Do events`  `Loop`  If this works well you would absolutely want to make the reading of locations faster so that it feels seamless when macro is actually doing something.

Comment: I go into work tomorrow and will try this, didnt expect an answer so fast:).  It looks like it will do the job. Much appreciated for all the help!